# Failed proptype classes material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this warning in my console:index.js:2178 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `classes` is marked as required in `WithStyles(Grid)`, but its value is `undefined`.
I have checked and made sure that classes is being passed on as a prop properly. I am not sure from where in my code this error is coming from. How can I get rid of this error?

```
const styles = theme => ({
  subtitle: {
    height: "auto"
  },
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    overflow: "hidden",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    margin: 0
  },
  gridList: {
    width: "80%",
    height: "auto"
  },
  icon: {
    color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)"
  }
});

class GridListings extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Grid>
          <GridList cellHeight={100} cols={3} className={classes.gridList}>
            <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={3} rows={1}>
              <ListSubheader
                component="div"
                style={{
                  fontSize: "60px",
                  marginTop: "20px"
                }}
              >
              Listings
              </ListSubheader>
            </GridListTile>
            {tileData.map(tile => (
              <GridListTile key={tile.img} cols={1} rows={3}>
                <img src={tile.img} alt={tile.title} />
                <GridListTileBar
                  className={classes.subtitle}
                  title={tile.title}
                  subtitle={<span>by: {tile.author}</span>}
                  actionIcon={
                    <IconButton className={classes.icon}>
                      <InfoIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  }
                />
              </GridListTile>
            ))}
          </GridList>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Grid.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(GridListings);
```

Comment: You are not passing classes as a prop to Grid, which is what the warning is saying.

Comment: @ChrisCousins but aren't I pulling classes from this.props at the render? All the styling that is in classes still works. How would I pass it in?

Comment: I believe the Grid component can’t see your props although the div containing it can, hence the warning. I think maybe <Grid classes={props.classes}>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom class is named `GridListings`, you export `GridListings` (with the withStyles), but you've defined your propTypes on Grid.propTypes:

```
Grid.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

Try changing it to:

```
GridListings.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```

My guess is that you're changing / modifying Grid's (a @material-ui component) propTypes, instead of your own component (GridListings).

Comment: ESLint on my machine (using airbnb configuration) does not like PropTypes.object.isRequired

Comment: some linters rules does not allow PropTypes.object to be used, what is the workaround then?

Comment: Using MUI I disabled that rule, otherwise I&#39;d have to define the entire structure of classes everywhere, which I'm not willing to do heh. Tradeoffs.